# How to listen a event handler in a class from other class in c# winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two classes, I Initialize Event handler in one class. and i need to listen this event handler from another class. In which way i can implement this ?

I have already try,

```
public event EventHandler NetworkLostEvent;
```

i use this code to fire the event

```
NetworkLostEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

How to listen this event from other class?

Comment: `yourClass.NetworkLostEvent += (sender, args) => { //your code }`

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to this event.

event can be subscribed using following lines.

```
//Lets say you have event defined in class2 or form2
form2.NetworkLostEvent += NetworkLostEventTriggered;

private void NetworkLostEventTriggered(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //logic
}
```

or,

```
//Lets say you have event defined in class2 or form2
form2.NetworkLostEvent += (s,ev) => {/*logic here*/ MessageBox.Show("event triggered"); };
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, what you want is a global event, for example: 1 datagridview having a cell value changed, automatically change cell values for any other similar instance of said datagridview, is this correct?

If this is the case heres how i handle event calling on multiple instances at the same time()

After searching around the net for a solution this is the one i came up with that fitted me perfectly. This is a "special" event that you yourself create and fire at will:

```
public class SpecialEvents
{
    //first custom event
    public EventArgs e = null;
    public event StartEventHandlerA StartedEventA;
    public delegate void StartEventHandlerA(SpecialEvents se, EventArgs e);
    public void StartEventA()
    {
        if (StartedEventA != null)
        {
            StartedEventA(this, e);
        }
    }

    //second custom event
    public event StartEventHandlerB StartedEventB;
    public delegate void StartEventHandlerB(SpecialEvents se, EventArgs e);
    public void StartEventB()
    {
        if (StartedEventB != null)
        {
            StartedEventB(this, e);
        }
    }

}
```

Now we need to subscribe to said custom events:

```
SpecialEvents special_Events = new SpecialEvents();
special_Events.StartedEventA += special_Events_StartedEventA;
```

And now the code to execute when that event is triggered:

```
void special_Events_StartedEventA(SpecialEvents se, EventArgs e)
{
   //do whatever you want for this specific class/object once that event is fired
}
```

And finally to trigger the event from wherever you want, whenever you want:

```
special_Events.StartEventA();
```

What this will do is simple, any dependant/independant code that is associated with that event that is supposed to fire at a specific time no matter which object triggers that event will fire for all objects and each object or class will execute its own script or code.

So that way you accomplish not only the listening feature that you want but can do a multitude of work while at it too.

Comment: Is there a reason why you didnt select an answear yet? have any questions with my method or someones method? If none of the answears are suitable at least please specify so so we can help you further.